# I have created a spring boot with DTO, Entity and also not able to store it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have created a spring boot with DTO, Entity and also generating entity from dto and vice versa but the data is not getting stored in the Postgres sql when i am trying to get the data its is showing null but creation is happing
**First is the controller class**

```
import com.school.Entity.StudentDetails;
import com.school.Service.StudentService;
import com.school.dto.StudentDetailDto;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
@CrossOrigin("*")
public class SchoolController {

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    public String test(){
        return "test";
    }
    @PostMapping("/uploadStudentData")
    public StudentDetailDto createStudentDetails(@RequestBody StudentDetailDto dto){
        return studentService.createStudentDetails(dto);
    }
    @GetMapping("/getAll")
    public List<StudentDetails> getAllStudentData(){
        return studentService.getAllStudentData();
    }
}
```

**Now the StudentDetailDto class**

```
import java.util.List;

public class StudentDetailDto {
    private Long id;
    private String branch;
    private List<StudentDto> student;

    //getter and setter
}
```

**now the StudenDto class**

```
public class StudentDto {
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private List<MarksListDto> marksList;
// getter and setter
}
```

**now the marks list class**

```
public class MarksListDto {
    private Long id;
    private String subjectName;
    private Integer marks;
// getter and setter
}
```

**now the SchoolDetails entity class**

```
@Entity
public class StudentDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String branch;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=Students.class, mappedBy="id", fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Students> student;
//getter and setter
}
```

**Now the Student Entity class**

```
@Entity
public class Students {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    @OneToMany(targetEntity=MarksList.class, mappedBy="id", fetch=FetchType.EAGER,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<MarksList> marksList;
//getter and setter
}
```

**Now the marks list entity**

```
@Entity
public class MarksList {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    private String subjectName;
    private int marks;
//getter and setter
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<StudentDetails, Long> {
}
```

**Now the most important that i am thinking there is something wrong is the servers**

```
import com.school.Entity.StudentDetails;
import com.school.Repository.StudentRepository;
import com.school.dto.StudentDetailDto;
import org.modelmapper.ModelMapper;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


@Service
public class StudentService {
    @Autowired
    StudentRepository studentRepository;

    @Autowired
    ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public StudentDetailDto createStudentDetails(StudentDetailDto dto) {
        validateDto(dto);
        StudentDetails studentDetails = generateEntityFromDto(dto);
        studentDetails = studentRepository.save(studentDetails);
        return generateDtoFromEntity(studentDetails);
    }

    private StudentDetails generateEntityFromDto(StudentDetailDto dto) {
        StudentDetails studentDetails = modelMapper.map(dto, StudentDetails.class);
        return studentDetails;
    }

    private StudentDetailDto generateDtoFromEntity(StudentDetails studentDetails){
        StudentDetailDto dto = modelMapper.map(studentDetails,StudentDetailDto.class);
        return dto;
    }

    private void validateDto(StudentDetailDto dto) {

    }

//    public List<StudentDetailDto> getAllStudentData() {
//        List<StudentDetailDto> dto = new ArrayList<>();
//         studentRepository.findAll().forEach(dto::add);
//         return dto;
//    }
//    public String createStudentDetails(StudentDetails studentDetails){
//        studentRepository.save(studentDetails);
//        return "Student details created";
//    }
//
    public List<StudentDetails> getAllStudentData() {
        return new ArrayList<>(studentRepository.findAll());

    }
}
```

**So when i am sending the data in postman it's showing me this it is storing null value i don't now y can anyone help me fix this and can help me to improve the code to the best version**

[image: postman image]

Comment: Try to name the fields in the request like they are mentioned in the response: `studentDto` instead of `student`

Comment: i have tried that its not working (field name is correct if u see the class)  @hjoeren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is working fine,I added following changes:

Define the ModelMapper bean in your Spring configuration:

```
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    return new ModelMapper();
}
```

dependency

```
<dependency>
<groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
<artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
<version>2.3.5</version>
```

Apart from above changes rest of the things are just fine,but Please optimize your code further.

Tested using postman

[image]
[image]

Comment: i have already defined the ModelMapper class and i have connected it with postgres sql but still not working for me

Comment: Your code is working for me, no problem with your code.Define the ModelMapper bean in your Spring configuration it will works.

Comment: can u upload that code and send me plz, in open link

Comment: i have already added the ModelMapper 
`@SpringBootApplication
public class SchoolApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(SchoolApplication.class, args);
 }
 @Bean
 public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
  return new ModelMapper();
 }

}
`
it is still not working can u plz send me ur code @Sibin

Answer (score 1):

**So after many google search i found out that maybe some constructor or some other thing was having problem , so i needed to define @Data annotation to the DTO class, and it worked**

```
import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class MarksListDto {
    private Long id;
    private String subjectName;
    private Integer marks;

    
}
```

Similar changes i did in my other DTO classes and it worked
and u have to add the import into ur dependency for gradle

```
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
```

Comment: You also need to add `testCompileOnly('org.projectlombok:lombok') testAnnotationProcessor('org.projectlombok:lombok')` if you are using lombok in your tests. See https://bootify.io/docs/spring-boot-with-lombok-in-intellij.html